# .Net Required Assembly References

Tags: .net, fluent-nhibernate, .net-assembly, assembly-references

I used ReSharper's "Optimize References" functionality on one of my C# projects, and it removed a pair of references to Fluent Nhibernate / Nhibernate.  I thought this was completely valid because I don't reference anything from them directly in that project.

When I rebuild the solution I was greeted with:

> The type 'FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

The project (which we will call **A**) doesn't directly reference Fluent Nhibernate, but does reference another project **B**, which uses Fluent NHibernate for mappings.  As far as the usage of **B** in **A**, I do use a class that has a FNH Map within it, but I don't use/reference that inner class anywhere in **A**.

I thought if a .Net project didn't reference an assembly in code directly, it didn't need to be in the project references. Or was this assumption wrong in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get this particular error, but I've seen similar problems with FNH / NH support DLLs, notably the Castle DLLS, and Log4Net.

Many tools will tell you these references are not required, but you get runtime errors if you try to eliminate them.

Comment: My friend told me that Visual Studio is just trying to save us pain requiring them on compile/startup, instead of halfway through running where it could possibly fail.